# How do I increase the line spacing between "Related Posts" and the first related entry?

Tags: html, css, line, spacing

[Line spacing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sSt7.jpg)

I recently added a "related post" widget on my blog and has followed the instructions step by step. I've had many successes in editing HTML on my blog when it comes to widgets and stuff but this one has kept me mulling for a day now. How can I increase the space between the RELATED POST and the first related entry so that the latter will not appear as tabbed and be in one line as the rest?

If the html code I added is any help, here it is:

```
<!--Related Posts Scripts and Styles Start-->
<!--Remove--><b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>

<style type='text/css'>
  #related-posts {
    float:center;
    text-transform:none;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
  }

  #related-posts .widget {
    padding-left:6px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
  }

  #related-posts .widget h2, #related-posts h2 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    font-family: Georgia, &#8220;Times New Roman&#8221;, Times, serif;
    margin-bottom: 0.75em;
    margin-top: 0em;
    padding-top: 0em;
  }

  #related-posts a {
    color:blue;
  }

  #related-posts a:hover {
    color:blue;
  }

  #related-posts ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 0 0px 0;
    padding:0px;
    text-decoration:bold;
    font-size:13px;
    text-color:#000000
  }

  #related-posts ul li {
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top:0px;
  }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var relatedpoststitle=&quot;Related Posts&quot;;
</script>
<script src='http://blogergadgets.googlecode.com/files/related-posts-for-blogger.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<!--Remove--></b:if>
<!--Related Posts Scripts and Styles End-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
line-height: px/em/pt
```

or add a bit of margin to the bottom to increase the spacing.

Comment: Actually, I just saw your picture. What is your "Related Posts" header wrapped in?

Comment: I don't know about what the header is wrapped in though. I already tried increasing the margin, to no avail. Where will I insert the line-height? Thanks @Winter

Comment: Since you didn't post any HTML. I'm going to take a logical guess @ where your css ties in with your html. Try increasing the margin-bottom or adding line-height to #related-posts .widget h2, #related-posts h2{}. If you see it change, then thats where the problem can be fixed. :)

Comment: It didn't work. :(( Sorry, but I don't even know the difference between HTML and CSS. :D Thanks though!

Comment: Can you post some of the html? or a link to the widget maybe? It's hard to tell which css tags are related to what html tags without both. :)

Comment: Hey thanks! I wanted to edit the body/description of my question above, but I'm having the Ooops msg. Anyway, I print screened another set of codes. I think this is what you are looking for. Kindly follow the link: http://img40.picoodle.com/i54r/bairuz/sd_674_u5l5x.jpg. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a linebreak tag or two (`<br/>`) after your "Related Posts" header.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried finding the Related Post header. <!--Related Posts Scripts and Styles Start--> Is this what you meant? Thanks @SimpleCoder.

Comment: I have no idea where it is, since you haven't given us the full source code. I just see CSS, not HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for that. I am not actually that knowledgeable with HTML nor CSS. I just followed instructions on this one blog I got the related post hack from. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#related-posts ul { clear: left; }
```

I suspect the issue is that the H2 is floated, but I understand that you cannot see the actual HTML. Without the HTML, it will be difficult to debug. I am guessing it is like this:

```
<div id="related-posts">
    <div class="widget">
        <h2>Related Posts</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>ESPN...</li>
            <li>Bruno...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! Could this be the HTML: http://img40.picoodle.com/i54r/bairuz/sd_674_u5l5x.jpg. Thanks!